# Tooltip in Prolog and Epilog

Tags: dynamic, tooltip

I have a question concerning Tooltip. I got a ParametricPlot and included two pictures and a dynamic point.

I try to use Tooltip for each of those 2 Objects. But it doesn't work. I am not quite sure, how to include the command in my code.

```
erde = ImageCrop[Import["https://cdn.goconqr.com/uploads/slide_property/image/8468/1d8af5e5-90e8-49f9-b20d-c3cef7fd7087.jpg"]];

arenstorf[y10_,y20_,y30_,y40_,mu_,tend_,ein_]:=Block[{problem,solArens,out},


  problem= {y1'[t] == y2[t],
  y2'[t] == 
  y1[t] + 2*y4[t] - 
  (1-mu)*(y1[t] + mu)/((y1[t] + mu)^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2) - 
  mu*(y1[t] - (1-mu))/((y1[t] - (1-mu))^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2),
  y3'[t] == y4[t],
  y4'[t] == 
  y3[t] - 2*y2[t] - 
  (1-mu)*(y3[t] )/((y1[t] + mu)^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2) - 
  mu*(y3[t] )/((y1[t] - (1-mu))^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2),
  y1[0] == y10,
  y2[0] == y20,
  y3[0] == y30,
  y4[0] == y40};

 solArens = NDSolve[problem,
  {y1, y2, y3, y4},
  {t, 0, tend}];

out= {ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[{y1[t],y3[t]}/.solArens],{t,0,tend},
      Frame->False,PlotPoints->40,
      Epilog-> 
        {PointSize[0.02],Black,Tooltip[Point/@({y1[ein],y3[ein]}/.solArens),
        "Satellit"]},
      Prolog ->  {
        Texture[erde],
        Polygon[{{-mu-.03, -.03}, {-mu+.03, -.03}, {-mu+.03,.03},
        {-mu-.03, .03}},
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
        ]}
      ] };
Return[out]]

Manipulate[arenstorf[0.994,0,0,-2.1139 ,0.012277471,5.4368,zeit],{zeit,0,5.4368}]
```

The point should move dynamically in the plot.
Could anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: There are several undefined variables in your code block. Please add values for these, or, even better, modify the code to be a minimal working example for your problem. The easier it is for others to replicate the issue the more likely you'll get some help.

Comment: Thank you, I will change the code to a working example.

Comment: @BobHanlon now it is really working. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I added the `Tooltip` to the `Prolog` and added satellite location to `Tooltip` in `Epilog`. I cleaned up the code a bit by removing unnecessary parts. To see the `Tooltip` you must put the pointer over the object. To see the `Texture` the `ImageSize` must be very large.

```
erde = ImageCrop[
   Import[
    "https://cdn.goconqr.com/uploads/slide_property/image/8468/1d8af5e5-90e8-\
49f9-b20d-c3cef7fd7087.jpg"
    ]];

arenstorf[y10_, y20_, y30_, y40_, mu_, tend_, ein_] :=
 Block[
  {problem, solArens, pt},
  problem = {
    y1'[t] == y2[t],
    y2'[t] == y1[t] + 2*y4[t] - (1 - mu)*(y1[t] + mu)/
        ((y1[t] + mu)^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2) -
      mu*(y1[t] - (1 - mu))/((y1[t] - (1 - mu))^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2),
    y3'[t] == y4[t],
    y4'[t] == y3[t] - 2*y2[t] - (1 - mu)*(y3[t])/
        ((y1[t] + mu)^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2) -
      mu*(y3[t])/((y1[t] - (1 - mu))^2 + (y3[t])^2)^(3/2),
    y1[0] == y10, y2[0] == y20, y3[0] == y30, y4[0] == y40};
  solArens = NDSolve[
     problem, {y1, y2, y3, y4}, {t, 0, tend}][[1]];
  (*  [[1]] removes outer list brackets  *)
  ParametricPlot[
   {y1[t], y3[t]} /. solArens,
   {t, 0, tend},
   Frame -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 40,
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Black,
     Tooltip[
      Point[pt = {y1[ein], y3[ein]} /. solArens],
      "Satellit\n" <> ToString[pt]]},
   Prolog -> {
     Texture[erde],
     Tooltip[
      Polygon[{{-mu - .03, -.03}, {-mu + .03, -.03},
        {-mu + .03, .03}, {-mu - .03, .03}},
       VertexTextureCoordinates ->
        {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
      "Erde"]},
   ImageSize -> 2000 (* large ImageSize needed to see Texture in Prolog *)]]

Manipulate[
 arenstorf[0.994, 0, 0, -2.1139, 0.012277471, 5.4368, zeit],
 {zeit, 0, 5.4368, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Hello,

I tried the following:

        Epilog->{PointSize[0.02],Black,Tooltip[Point[#], "Satellit"]&/@({y1[ein],y3[ein]}/.solArens)}

but it doesn't work. Is your example working for a set of point or for a "dynamic point" too? I gues I don't quite understand the part "& /@ pts"..

Comment: Sorry, I answered your question before editing the code. Now my example is working. I hope my question get clearer now :)

Comment: Thanks for all your effors @BobHanlon. Does this code work on your machine? I tried it out on Mathematica Online and the Tooltip-option didn't work. I'll try it out on another machine tomorrow and will report, if it was successful. :)

Comment: @Merlin - I just copied the above code into a notebook and it evaluated just fine.